# Adding overlapping annotations to map

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkannotation

I have an array of coordinates and I already know how to add it on a map as annotations.
What I'd like to do now is the following:

1. each annotation should be a red circle (no pins) that represents a fixed radius of 1 Km around the coordinates. That means that if I zoom in or out the map, the circle should adjusts itself to always represent a 1 Km radius;
2. if two or more circles overlaps, their color intensity should increase. For example, three or four overlapping circles will produce a solid red circle.

That's all. I have no idea where to start with this, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter you can use below code but you will have to tweak it little to make it of your use:

```
in .h file confirm to MKMapViewDelegate

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Then,

```
in "viewDidLoad"
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = {X cordinate, Y cordinate};
//--> Add  overlay
MKCircle *mCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:center radius:1000]; //set radius    as per your need
[self.mapView addOverlay:mCircle];
```

Then,

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
   MKCircleView *cirView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
   [cirView setFillColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [cirView setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   [cirView setAlpha:0.3f];
    return cirView;
}
```

I think this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna try it now.

Comment: Ok, it's working perfectly. I've only eliminated the strokeColor because I don't like it. Thanks again.